# Functional interface that return void and passes a boolean parameter

Tags: java, functional-interface

I'm making a method to be executed in another thread because of the time it may take. However, I want to inform the caller that the operation iswill be finished and if it was successful. To do so, I would need a functional interface that returns nothing (I don't need the result of my callback) and that passes a boolean.

Example code:

```
public boolean send(Command command) {
    try {
        //long stuff
        return true;
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        //logging error
        return false;
    }
}

public void sendAsync(Command command, MyCallback callback) {
    new Thread(() -> {
        boolean successful = send(command);
        if(callback != null)
            callback.call(successful);
    }).start();
}
```

Something like:

```
void call(boolean successful);
```

Is it already present in Java or do I have to make one myself ?

Comment: How would you know the operation was successful if it returns void?

Comment: @JakeMiller the functional interface isn't doing the operation, it's just reporting if the operation was successful and is executed after the actual operation

Comment: What's preventing you from defining this yourself? If you don't need the result, then why do you have a parameter?

Comment: @cricket_007 To improve clarity. I don't like reinventing objects that are available in Java standard library. I also gave an example code to explain.

Comment: I know what you're asking exists in RxJava, but a `Callable` is the closest you'll get in the Java8 standard library

Comment: @cricket_007 Callable doesn't allow passing values and has a return type.

Comment: All I said was that it's the closest thing, not that it's what you wanted

Comment: What about Function interface from Java8?

`class TestFunc implements Function<Boolean, Void>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `void call(boolean successful)` can be represented by a [`Consumer<Boolean>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html) as `void accept(Boolean b)`, which is built into java. That would allow you avoid having to make your own functional interface.

Hence:

```
public void sendAsync(Command command, Consumer<Boolean> callback) {
    new Thread(() -> {
        boolean successful = send(command);
        if(callback != null)
            callback.accept(successful);
    }).start();
}
```